# python dictionary attribute error

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the following code to 'invert' a dictionary. Some of the keys in the source dictionary have synonyms in other entries, so where there are multiple values for an inverted key I am trying to append eg commandante = captain and so does capitano = captain, so I am trying to achieve captain : commandante, capitano. I have used defaultdict which I naively thought would solve my problem, but I continuely get an Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

```
def form_eng_dict():
    #temp_dict =  pickle.load( open( "penult_dict.txt", "rb" ) )
    temp_dict ={'commandante': 'captain', 'capitano':'skipper,captain', 'alaggio': 'towing, hauling'}
    try:
        e_dict =  pickle.load( open( "penult_eng.txt", "rb" ) )    
    except:
        e_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for key, value in temp_dict.items():
        for word in value.split(','):
            word.strip(' ')
            #print(word)
            if word not in e_dict:
                e_dict[word] = key   
            else:
                e_dict[word].append(key) # causes error

    for key, value in e_dict.items():
        print(key, value)
    pickle.dump(temp_dict, open( "penult_eng.txt", "wb" ) )
```

I am uncertain what I am doing incorrectly and how to solve the issue.I don't understand how I am creating a string. I am sure that I am making an absolutely basic error and will feel really stupid when you point out my error(s)! But thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify:

```
e_dict[word] = key
```

to:

```
e_dict[word] = [key]
```

You want to be able to append, so you should create an initial list with `[key]` inside - otherwise you're trying to append to a string which is why you're getting:

> Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'